# Cannot assign requested address in Docker .NET Console client application

Tags: c#, .net, docker, api, docker-compose

I am trying to learn some docker, i managed to setup API image/container and it works fine, I can get response from the API when i'll go through web browser. However my console client can't get a request to my API and I am not sure why. The only error i get is Cannot assign requested address in docker CLI.

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static string apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

static void Main()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Console started.");
    RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static async Task RunAsync()
{
    // Update port # in the following line.
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64195/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    System.Console.WriteLine(client.BaseAddress);
    
    try
    {
        var value = await GetValueAsync();
    }
}
}
```

And the method that generate the error:

```
static async Task<Value> GetValueAsync()
   {
        Value value = null;

     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl + "/value");
     System.Console.WriteLine("TEST");
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         value = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Value>();
     }
     return value;
}
```

Program stops and returns an error on the client.GetAsync line, it never gets to the writeline("TEST"). Anyone knows what could be the problem? Everything else works until the request. On the request the Cannot assign requested address shows up and stops the container/program.

Comment: Having the same issue, wondering if you ended up solving this one yourself?